# How to create and save a table for each row in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Goal**: I have a table of events with a `ts` timestamp column. For each event in the event table, I want to search in a separate data table and find all logs that are within a time delta from that event. I want to store those logs in a file labeled by that event.

**What I've tried so far**: I have a Spark SQL query for getting a basic count for the data points near each event.

```py
counts = spark.sql("""
    SELECT e.ts,
           count(d.*)
    FROM events AS e
    LEFT JOIN data AS d ON d.ts <= u.ts + delta AND d.ts => u.ts - delta
""")
```

How do I change the counts in the query to tables (or some other collection) of logs and then write those tables to separate files? Ideally in cheaper ways, since the dataset is very large.

Edit: **Sample Input**

```
Event Table
+-------+----------+
|     id|      time|
+-------+----------+
|   2468|         0|
|   1234|        10|
+-------+----------+

Data Table
+-------+----------+
|     id|      time|
+-------+----------+
|      a|        -1|
|      b|         2|
|      c|         5|
|      d|         8|
|      e|        10|
|      f|        11|
|      g|        12|
+-------+----------+
```

**Corresponding desired output**: The following tables, one for each event table row, written to parquet files. Assume that `delta = 5`.

```
Event 2468
+-------+----------+
|     id|      time|
+-------+----------+
|      a|        -1|
|      b|         2|
|      c|         5|
+-------+----------+

Event 1234
+-------+----------+
|     id|      time|
+-------+----------+
|      c|         5|
|      d|         8|
|      e|        10|
|      f|        11|
|      g|        12|
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: could you give us sample data from the two tables, and a sample of the desired output

Comment: Of course. Just added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the setup for the example (I registered the tables since it seems you are already working with tables in the first place)

```
>>> events = sc.parallelize([(2468, 0), (1234, 10)]).toDF(["id", "time"])
>>> data = sc.parallelize([("a", -1),("b",  2),("c",  5),("d",  8),("e", 10),("f", 11),("g", 12)]).toDF(["id", "time"])
>>> events.registerTempTable("events")
>>> data.registerTempTable("data")
```

so we want to join the two tables only when the `time` columns are withing `delta` of each other, that would be `abs(data.time - events.time) <= 5`, you can format this for different deltas

```
>>> events_range = spark.sql("SELECT events.id as event, data.id, data.time FROM events JOIN data ON abs(data.time - events.time) <= 5")
>>> events_range.show()
+-----+---+----+
|event| id|time|
+-----+---+----+
| 2468|  a|  -1|
| 2468|  b|   2|
| 2468|  c|   5|
| 1234|  c|   5|
| 1234|  d|   8|
| 1234|  e|  10|
| 1234|  f|  11|
| 1234|  g|  12|
+-----+---+----+
```

and now we want to get each unique event of the result as it own dataframe

```
>>> eventNames = events.select("id").collect() #get all events
>>> eventNames
[Row(id=2468), Row(id=1234)]
>>> for evt in eventNames:
...    evt_df = events_range.where(f"event = {evt['id']}").drop("event")
...    evt_df.show()
...
+---+----+
| id|time|
+---+----+
|  a|  -1|
|  b|   2|
|  c|   5|
+---+----+

+---+----+
| id|time|
+---+----+
|  c|   5|
|  d|   8|
|  e|  10|
|  f|  11|
|  g|  12|
+---+----+
```

and there you'd save them instead of printing... Also if some events don't meet the criteria you can get empty dataframes here.